# PhpStorm 2018.2 javascript code invalid autocomplete

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.2

Two questions:

1.

Why code autocomplete is showing me `.set` methods from other libraries while having proper import from particular one (screenshot)?

[image]

2.

Why, while importing `lodash`, I have *"Cannot resolve symbol"* in here?

[image]

I know, that to prevent from displaying this warning I need to load `@types/lodash` in Javascript libraries settings, but... why this information is not loaded automatically from `node_modules` directory?

Comment: What is your javascript version set to under the languages settings?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I've got "Flow" in there.

Comment: both issues indicate that properties can't be resolved during static code analysis (because they are added dynamically, or because of code analyser issues). Installing Typescript definitions helps in most cases. This can be done right in the editor - Place the cursor at the import statement with your library, press `Alt+Enter`, and choose *Install TypeScript definitions for better type information*. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

Comment: @lena Ok, I knew about those Typescript definitions. But why they are not downloaded automatically in regards to "dependencies" section inside `package.json`? For every lib I must do it myself manually for every project. Same thing when removing any library - will not update.
And why PhpStorm is suggesting me about `set()` from all other libraries  (which are not imported) instead of saying that "mori" library does not have that function (if it really cannot be resolved from that proper import)?